# How to pass extracted values from mysql data base from one php file to another

Tags: php, pdo

I want to pass the specific extracted userID  for each instance to another php file full_details.php  so it generates a page dynamically

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT userID, userDate, userName, userAge, userSex, userPic, userLocation, userStatus, userDetails FROM tbl_users ORDER BY userID DESC');
$stmt->execute();
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0)
{
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        extract($row);
        ?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                  <div class="single-product">
                    <figure>
            <img src="user_images/<?php echo $row['userPic']; ?>" />
            <figcaption>


                        <div class="read-more">
                          <a href="full_details.php"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Full Details</a>
                        </div>

                      </figcaption>
                    </figure>

                    <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $row['userName']."&nbsp;/&nbsp;"."age :".$row['userAge']; ?></a></h4>

                    <h5><a href="#"><?php echo $row['userStatus'] ?></a></h5>
                  </div> <!-- end .single-product -->
                </div> <!-- end .grid-layout -->
```

Comment: ok and the problem is what exactly?

Comment: And get rid of `extract($row);`

Comment: and why was this tagged as both mysqli and pdo? you do know that those are two different animals altogether. Edit: to which the mysqli tag was removed. I hope you're not mixing apis here.

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on besides 2/3 of a PHP script...

Comment: I hope we won't be staring at this question till the cows come home in order to get clarification. This has been happening way too often. Seems like asking for clarification is like pulling teeth. Ok, I'm out.

Comment: Oh but wait, not so fast........... you posted this already http://stackoverflow.com/q/42421843/1415724 and gotten an answer. This question should be closed as an exact duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PDO to extract specific values from mysql database using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42421843/using-pdo-to-extract-specific-values-from-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I want the extracted values to be used in another php file without connecting to the database again? like when I click on the href link   "full_details.php". I want the values to be used in that file

Comment: Not sure what is being asked here.

Comment: Not sure many people feel like posting an answer, since you still haven't accepted the answer you got on your last question, which you confirmed worked for you, several hours ago.

Comment: The code already generates an image gallery. Now I want  it to pass the values from each generated image into the php file full_details.php  so that when I click the href = "full_details.php" it will generate another page using the same details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easy to understand what you are asking...

*I want to pass the specific extracted userID for each instance to another php file full_details.php so it generates a page dynamically*

You would need to pass that ID in the URI for that href then right?  Something like this:

```
<div class="read-more">
  <a href="full_details.php?user_id=<?= $row['userID'] ?>"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Full Details</a>
</div>
```

Then on full_details.php you can retrieve that `GET parameter` like so:

```
$userId = (isset($_GET['user_id')) ? $_GET['user_id'] : null;
```

Does that help?